# Use Google Analytics to Track Home Page Links Differently

Tags: 7, google-analytics

We use Google Analytics on our Drupal website. We are re-doing our current homepage and we would like to track the links on our homepage separately from the rest of the tracking. For instance, if you navigate to the "Contact Us" section from anywhere on the website *except* the homepage, it logs it as such. However, if you navigate there directly from the homepage, it notes that the person arrived there from the homepage and there is pretty much a separate statistic for this.

We would like to see where people are drawn to when they land on the homepage, so this is why we would like to implement this.

Alternatively, if Google Analytics can't do this, is there another potential solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in google analytics by creating a segment rule that is based on behavior flow.   Google Tags can also do this (recommended) or you can add a custom field using the drupal google analytics module to facilitate tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can see the Landing pages and their behavior flow in your Google Analytics account. Login your Google Analytics account and go to "**Reporting > Behavior > Behavior Flow**", and you will see all the landing pages and interaction. The home page should be the "**/**".